# Is playing the tag-mode mini game necessary to expand the Pioneer Town?

Tags: dragon-quest-iv

In *Dragon Quest IV: Chapters of the Chosen* (Nintendo DS), when you first discuss the Pioneer Town with Hank Hoffman, Jr., he mentions that in order to grow the town, you must play a tag-mode mini game to recruit pioneers to come to the town.

Is this necessary to get the town to grow to its maximum size? I have read a few walkthroughs about it and they are not worded very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I personally did it without it.

You just have to get the [five permanent immigrants](https://web.archive.org/web/20090704184420/http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/index.php/Dragon_Quest_IV:_Chapters_Of_The_Chosen_-_DS/Sidequests) to get to full size (castle).